How to highlight a row by looping column values via conditional formatting
Trying to find a way to highlight a row based on a column value.
Tried out
=countif(index($G$4:$G),A2)
But this only matches one cell and not the entire row. Have use =Search function but i was not able to loop the G column values only able to give static values.



You may try:
Apply to range: A4:E
Custom formula is:
=not(iserror(regexextract(join(" ",$A4:$E4),textjoin("|",1,$G$4:$G))))



Thank you so much. This solves my issue. Is there a way to overcome case sensitive issue in this.

Incase you do not want to match Apple with Applesauce & also wish to match Apple with apple then try with: =not(iserror(regexextract(join(" ",$A4:$E4),"(?i)\b("&textjoin("|",1,$G$4:$G)&")\b")))

Is there a way to match with exact content, like i have Green Apple and i dont want it to be highlighted for Apple. I need to change the code to match the exact content of the G column

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Sorry for being clear on the input. I have added the exact scenario in this sheet. Kindly do check Sample Sheet

test the range A3:E10 with =isnumber(+tocol(bycol($A3:$E3,lambda(Σ,index(xmatch(tocol(split(trim(Σ),char(10))),$G$3:$G$10)))),3))

Another solution:
Applied to A4:E. Custom formula is:
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH($A4:$E4,"(?i)\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b",1,$G$4:$G)&"\b"))



For some reason this code is not working on my actual data set while it works on the sample code

you probably didn't set it up correctly. If you reproduce the issue in a sample sheet and share it here I can take a look.

Sorry for being clear on the input. I have added the exact scenario in this sheet. Kindly do check Sample Sheet

the reason it higlights row 6 is because A6 contains "apple", which is a word in column G (G3 specifically). If you only want to higlight the rows with a value that exactly matches the values in column G use: =SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH($A3:$E3,"(?i)^("&TEXTJOIN("|",1,$G$3:$G)&")$")). But then this won't higlight rows like row 5 because there's not any value in the row that exactly matches one of the values in column G.

Thank you for the answer. Got this working from the code by @rockinfreakshow
